# use MVC like validation in WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, validation

I'm using MVC with entity framework for a while.
and now i need to make a wpf application and I'm looking for a way to validate like the model-state in WPF

This is how my class looks

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any easy way for me to check if its valid?

what I'm really trying to avoid is to have to write all the validation rules

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, I had to create a interface called IValidateable which extends INotifyDataErrorInfo where I define a method Validate that I can pass the property name to or leave it blank to validate the entire object.

The INotifyDataErrorInfo is an .Net interface that allows the validation to be asynchronous and has already a property HasErrors to check the object after it has been validated.

I then implemented all of the required methods in a base class, when I need to validate the entire object, this base class uses reflection to list the properties and then validate each one.

In the base class I have an virtual method like so:

```
protected virtual void PerformValidation (String Property) {}
```

My models override this method and do the specific validation required. This method is not required to be override and as I said, you can add support to attributes in the base class.

You can extend the IDataErrorInfo instead of the INotifyDataErrorInfo if you don't need asynchronous validation.

Then I can just do something like this:

```
 SomeModel.Validate ();

 if (SomeModel.HasErrors)
     Do Something...
```

Or:

```
if (!SomeModel.Validate ())
    Do Something...
```